# HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: apache-poi

I am getting this compilation error

```
HSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
```

when i am using this class in Selenium webdriver.I have added the respective jar, poi 3.9 jar, but still unable to resolve this compilation error.

Comment: What all jars you have added?

Comment: i have added poi jar 3.9

Answer (score 2):

Hi please update your apache poi to The latest stable release is Apache POI 3.14 from https://poi.apache.org/download.html and then import the Apache POI jars form

1. jars inside poi-3.14
2. jars inside lib

Comment: i have downloaded the file poi-src-3.1.tar.gz. I have extracted the .tar file but i'm unable to find the jar file required.could you please mention the path

Comment: do not download .tar.gz instead please download poi-bin-3.14.zip (27MB, signed) (just below the .tar.gz)

Answer (score 2):

**Look for "poi-3.17.jar"!!!**

1. Download from "https://poi.apache.org/download.html".
2. Click the one Binary Distribution -> poi-bin-3.17-20170915.tar.gz
3. Unzip the file download and look for this "poi-3.17.jar".

Problem solved and errors disappeared.

Hope this answer your question!!!

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates that the class could not be found on the classpath of your application. Did you make sure that the POI jar is added?

Comment: yes, i have added the poi jar..but still it showing the same compilation error